# Magento 2 : Buy X and get Y Free in custom module..How it set in admin and fronted?

Tags: magento2, product, price, addtocart, catalog-price-rules

Magento2 default in set Cart Rule get X qty get the Y free same logic in my custom module in the set but I was confused about which file in set code?

Comment: Use $item->setCustomPrice(0);      $item->setOriginalCustomPrice(0);  user both at time

Comment: Do you not have to set the price against the quote Item? I.e. just $item->setPrice(0); Also, you haven't defined $quoteItem in your example.

Comment: example 'test' SKU 5 product already in the cart and I have added also 45 then carts in total item 52 but price calculate only 50 prodcut..@ Richard & Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

            $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');           
            $typeId=$item->getProduct()->getTypeId();                                   
            $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct(); 
                foreach ($item->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $pItem) {

                       $getprice =0;    // set price            

                        $pItem->setCustomPrice($getprice);
                        $pItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($getprice); 
                        $pItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);             

                }

            return $this;


        }
```

Comment: It's working like cart product total price 0..i need just 52 into 2 product price 0..same product all.

Comment: hello like buy X qty and get X-free qty cart rule type.

Comment: Hello I was updated my question..please reply if you know about it.